# getParent for jframe that is attribute of a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have a jpanel that contains a jframe, when i press on a button on that jframe I want to access the jpanel

I use the method `getParent()` but  that doesn't work

```
public class StorePanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {
private TableProducts tableproducts;
......
}
```

code of jframe to get the parent

```
private void confirmActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

        StorePanel store=(StorePanel)this.getParent();
        store.getitemTable();
    .........
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you want to be trying to get a `JPanel` as the _parent_ of a `JFrame`? I expect the `JPanel` is a child of the `JFrame`, but regardless you don't show how the `StorePanel` is added to the code trying to access it (`confirmActionPerformed`).

Comment: Generally, you should put `JPanel` inside `JFrame`, because `JFrame` is a top level component and `JPanel` is a general purpose panel for the content (except menu bar)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  Nobody here seems to believe your claim that you are adding a `JFrame` to a `JPanel`.  An SSCCE will either prove your point or at least clear up the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

[JComponent.getTopLevelAncestor()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getTopLevelAncestor%28%29) presuming the same conditions as the other people who replied.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your post is in error, that the JFrame contains the JPanel. If so, and if no other containers exist between the JPanel and the JFrame, getting the parent will likely get the JFrame's contentPane. If you want to get the JFrame, then try the SwingUtilities#getWindowAncestor method on the JPanel.

Otherwise, if you are trying to get a JPanel that is held by the JFrame, then you can iterate recursively through it's components (via the getComponents method), but the easiest way is to pass a reference of the JPanel to the JFrame when one or the other are created or added into the other.

Comment: No error!! I create an instance from the JFrame from this JPanel
and When I finish from this instanc I press a button and I want the JPanel to be updated!!

Comment: @Raafat: what the heck do you mean by `"I create an instance from the JFrame from this JPanel"`? I think that you will want to edit your original post and clarify the situation greatly by giving us a **lot** more detail than you've given us so far.  The statement above is just nonsense.